# Mixing operator with unix_timestamp yields unexpected null

Tags: sql, mariadb, unix-timestamp

My table has some `TIMESTAMP` columns, for which I am running a query to get the most recent one as a Unix timestamp. Suppose all the columns are zeroed (they are `default '0'`), i.e. I didn't set the value yet.

- If I select each column with `unix_timestamp(col)`, it will return `0` for each column:

```sql
select unix_timestamp(`last_ip_ok`), unix_timestamp(`last_ip_error`), unix_timestamp(`last_ownership_ok`), unix_timestamp(`last_ownership_error`) from `websites`;
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp(`last_ip_ok`) | unix_timestamp(`last_ip_error`) | unix_timestamp(`last_ownership_ok`) | unix_timestamp(`last_ownership_error`) |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| 0                            | 0                               | 0                                   | 0                                      |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

- If I select the `greatest` of all columns, it will return the zero timestamp, that is, `0000-00-00 00:00:00`:

```sql
select greatest(`last_ip_ok`, `last_ip_error`, `last_ownership_ok`, `last_ownership_error`) from `websites`;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| greatest(`last_ip_ok`, `last_ip_error`, `last_ownership_ok`, `last_ownership_error`) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- However, if I combine the functions and run `unix_timestamp(greatest(cols...))`, it just returns `null`:

```sql
select unix_timestamp(greatest(`last_ip_ok`, `last_ip_error`, `last_ownership_ok`, `last_ownership_error`)) from `websites`;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp(greatest(`last_ip_ok`, `last_ip_error`, `last_ownership_ok`, `last_ownership_error`)) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| <null>                                                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is unexpected, I expected the return value to be `0` since it should be equivalent to `unix_timestamp('0000-00-00 00:00:00')`, which is the return value of `greatest(cols...)`. Is this correct, or is it possibly a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you do:

```
 SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

you will get NULL because it is not a valid date for the UNIX_TIMESTAMP range.

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) returns the number of seconds between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and datetime. Thus datetime needs to be a VALID date and time between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and 2038-01-19 03:14:07. If it is not valid or not in that range, UNIX_TIMESTAMP will return NULL.

I am puzzled why you are getting "0" in your first query. When I test (even with SQL mode allowing zero dates)

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(0);
```

I get an expected NULL result. We need to have the example data dump to investigate further.

Comment: The example data is just the four columns as `timestamp not null default '0'`, then insert a row without filling the columns

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused.  When I run:

```
select unix_timestamp('0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

I get `NULL`, not `0`.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=29ee4b616949a8fa9a477450dc9dca41) is a db<>fiddle.

I can't think of a reason why your first query would return `0`, rather than